# Create method in subclass that prints out method from superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have two classes, `Send` (superclass) and `Message` (subclass). I want to create a method called `Summary` that prints the users name (found in the superclass).

I have created a method in the Send class called `getName`, however I'm not sure how to complete the task.

`Send` class:

```
public class Send {
    private String username;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public void getName(){
        username = "Adam";
    }
}
```

`Message` class:

```
public class Message extends Send {
    private String message;

    public void summary(){
        System.out.println("Message post from" + getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for the layout, I'm not entirely sure what happened.

Comment: Please edit, select your code, and click the `{}` button to format as code.

Comment: Message is extending Post and not Send like you told, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: right now your `getName()` is only setting the value of username to "Adam", it is also declared "void" so it will not return anything.

Comment: Please mind that Java methods should start with a lowercase letter. So change `Summary` to `summary`. ([Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html))

Comment: Silly mistakes fixed, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getter` is actually a static `setter` I think you want to replace

```
public void getName(){
    username = "Adam";
}
```

With

```
public String getName(){
    return this.username;
}
```

And

```
public void setName(final String pUsername)
{
    this.username = pUsername;
}
```

Then somewhere call

```
super.setName("aNameToGive");
```

and

```
System.out.println(super.getName());
```

Would print `aNameToGive`

Also, your design is pretty strange. I think you want to put your `main` In the `Message` class. Then from there initiate a `constructor`, then in the constructor, call your new methods. If you want to call the methods from the `main` you will have to change everything to `static` but that would be evil for that kind of work.

Something like

```
public class Message extends Send {
    private String message;

    public Message(){
        super.setName("Adam");
        System.out.println(super.getName());
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Message();
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Send {
    private String username;

    public void setName(final String pUsername)
    {
        this.username = pUsername;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code below i initialized the username at the declaration moment, you can modify that name by calling the setter method in any other class as the method is marked public (like what i did in Test class).

You can test that code by running the Test class:

**Send class:**

```
public class Send {

    private String username = "Adam";


    public String getUsername(){   

        retur username;

    }

    public Void setUsername(String username){ 

        this.username = username;

    }

}
```

**Message class:**

```
public class Message extends Send {

    private String message;

    public void getSummary(){

        System.out.println("Message post from" + getUsername());

    }

}
```

You can use an external class to call you getSummary method like below, or just copy the main method and paste it in your Message class:

**Test Class**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


       Message msg = new Message();

       // you can add this method call to change the user name before printing it
       // msg.setUsername("Smith");

       msg.getSummary();

    }

}
```

**NB:** I edited your method naming in order to follow naming conventions

Comment: He might get the desired output, but this won't teach the OP at all a good design. Why not tell him to remove everything and call `System.out.println("Adam");` in the `main` then ?

Comment: i will try to improve my answer, but i suugested that because that may help him to understand inheritance more

Comment: This won't even work, you are still only _setting_ username to "Adam" and not returning anything, `System.out.println("Message post from" + getUsername());` will not print "Adam"

Comment: @chancea you are right, thanks for the notice, i just updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Put your static void main class inside the message method and call summary method from that method.